# Each bone is deformind the entire mesh and not just a part of it

Tags: armature, bones, weight-painting

I am still an amateur to blender and I usually use automatic weights for my Character's armatures, but this time I have encountered a problem in which the automatic weights makes so a bone has a way larger influence radius than it should. how can I fix it?

Here's a video of me demonstrating the problem
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7wGtnDnQXYw&feature=youtu.be

Comment: you often need to make some correction after parenting, either with the brush in Weight Paint mode, or with the Vertex Groups list in Properties > Data > Vertex Groups

Comment: Could you upload your .blend file on https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so I can check and try to help you?